# Flickering lights on same switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

Hello I’m curious about possible causes for the following scenario:

I have two lights on a three-way switch and they flicker every once in a while.

Tonight they started flickering quite violently (worse than I have ever seen before). I recently replaced the switches (not because I suspected they were problematic, but just to change the color), but the lights flickered prior to replacing these switches.

Normally I would suspect the cause of this to be lose wiring on the three way switch, but when I flip the relevant circuit off and on the problem seems to go away. This is especially odd as these are the only lights that flicker and there are quite a few lights on this circuit. This is in the newer part of our house which has modern Romex wiring.

Any ideas what may cause this behavior given the above circumstances?

Comment: Hrm.  Are these incandescent, fluorescent, or LED?  And do they flicker in unison, or separately?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel good question - the lights were flickering in unison and they are LED. I’ve also recently replaced the bulbs as they were far too yellow before - they flickered before the bulbs were replaced.

Comment: Did you wire the switches using backstabs or side-screws?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel side screws

Comment: You mentioned there are other lights on this circuit. What is on this circuit? Those things could also cause this. Please list them off. (Even if not on, just plugged in). Also, are the bulbs dimmable, and are these switches dimmer enabled? Are they smart switches? Were they before?

Comment: They are dimmer enabled and they are on a three way switch with one dimmer master and one non-dimmer slave switch. As far as I know the circuit is entirely dedicated to lights and is labeled as such “first floor lights”. The master is a standard 3-way Lutron CL dimmer decorator switch and the slave is an Enerlites 3-way decorator switch. Previously they were both Lutron but otherwise the same setup just different colors. Bulbs are definitely dimmable. We have them all over the house on dimmers and had them in our last house + they are listed as dimmable.

Comment: I'd try temporarily replacing the master and slave with regular plain-old traditional three-way switches and see if that eliminates the problem. If it does, you need better and more-compatible dimmers or a different arrangement for dimming